# Permission denied error while copying the files to another user directory using WINSCP?

Tags: ssh

I have a few folder in one of my ubuntu machine in the directory `/export/home/` as  -

```
user1
user2
user3
```

Whenever any user login to that machine, it always takes him to that directory as a default. If I am `user1`, and I am logging in to that machine, then after logging, if I do `pwd`, I always see -

`/export/home/user1`

Now what I am supposed to do is, I have opened a winscp on my desktop as `user1` to connect to that machine, and then I need to copy a file from my `desktop` to `user2` folder but whenever I try to open `user2` folder in winscp, it always gives me -

`Permission denied error..`

Is there any way, I can ask `user2` to give me permission (by logging into his account from putty) to copy the files using `winscp` from my desktop to `user2` folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you log in to an Ubuntu server as `user1`, then generally you do not have permission to add anything to `user2`'s home directory.

If you want to be able to, then here is one way you could get permissions. Execute these commands on the server (they will need to be executed by someone with `sudo` ability).

```
sudo addgroup sharers
sudo adduser user1 sharers
sudo adduser user2 sharers
sudo chgrp sharers /home/user2
sudo chmod g+w /home/user2
```

Then `user1` will be able to drop files in to the `/home/user2` directory.

Finer grain control could be obtained using Access Control Lists (ACL's), but I won't go in to that here.

Comment: Thanks David. We all have sudo access to that machine. But is it necessary to create a group? Can user2 gives me access to copy the files by logging into his acccount from putty using some chmod command?

Comment: He could do `chmod o+w .` - which would let anyone put files in his directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the owner rights of the file you need to copy to the user2 folder?
`chown user1:user1 file.ext`

after that you could change the r/w/x/ rights on that file.
`chmod 0755 file.ext`

Another way you could look into are the group memberships.

The created users, have their own groups?

If you are using gnome/unity, you could take a look at the users and groups management tool 
`users-admin` from a terminal window `Ctrl+Alt+t`. If you don't have this tool installed enter the next command in a terminal window.
`sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools`, this will install the tool users-admin.

With this tool you can grant user1 acces rights in user2 and/or user2 group, and vice versa for user2 and user3.
Another thing comes to mind, take a closer look to ssh/scp/winscp group and/or usage rights for the user1, user2, user3 account.